# How to represent Spring properties, with a value and sub-properties, in YML?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml, properties-file

I'm working with a library that uses nested properties for configuration.

E.g.

```java
@Value("${foo.bar}") String fooBar;
@Value("${foo.bar.baz}") String fooBarBaz;
```

This can be represented successfully in the following properties file:

```
foo.bar=abc
foo.bar.baz=xyz
```

However, I've been unable to find a way to represent this in a YML file. Can this even be done?
I've tried the following:

```yaml
// Invalid (ScannerException).
foo:
  bar: abc
    baz: xyz

// Invalid (NullPointerException).
foo:
  bar:
    ~: abc
    baz: xyz

// Invalid (DuplicateKeyException).
foo:
  bar: abc
  bar:
    baz: xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I just realized this could be done by collapsing the nesting into the key.

E.g.

```yaml
foo:
  bar: abc
  bar.baz: xyz
```